# Mobile app back end for Geolocation queries

Tags: azure, firebase, xamarin, geolocation

I have a mobile App, done with Xamarin and I'm looking to implement the backend, but I'm lost because I have a specific need.

My app. should be able to do some "geolocalized" queries, by example :

SELECT * FROM MyProducts Where Category = "Fashion" ORDER BY Distance(Item.Position, Me.Position)

Do you see ?

Is it the way it works? For example, a famous mobile app. like Tinder are looking for peoples around you, is it the way they do that?

But so, for this, I need a database that supports such queries!

About performance, is there a difference with SQL and NoSQL database, pro & cons?

I was looking for Azure, because it seems to be the standard tool for Xamarin, but can't find any information about that kind of queries!

About other possibilities, I have seen... Firebase, etc... I don't know at all!

Any help is welcome

Thanks

Comment: This is strictly an opinion (and not StackOverflow material), but for a backend, I like GeoFire (via Firebase), but the way GeoFire encodes lat/lang into a searchable/indexable single string it can be adopted to any NoSQL/SQL database (I've used it in Sqlite, MySQL, MSSQL, Cosmos, etc..).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm unable to find a Firebase API for Xamarin, none of them seems to install correctly. And for Geofire, there is no library at all :-(

Comment: I ported the Java version of Geofire to C#, not sure if there is a OSS version of it floating around or not. Not sure what the Firebase issue is, I use it on Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, but I suppose that your library is not open source ? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience I can tell you that Azure does provide a few options that would allow you to work with geospatial data.

The first is Cosmos DB (DocumentDB) and it nicely integrates with Xamarin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mobile-apps-with-xamarin)

The second would be Azure Search. The advantage here is that you can use different types of data-sources to work with. (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/videos/azure-search-and-geospatial-data/)

I hope that helps.